# Continuous top on linux

Tags: linux, performance, process

On Linux, is it possible to record the running processes (just which process is running when), for some period of time? It would be like getting a log from top. The reason I want to do that is that I have performance issues with my process, and the box I am working on does not provide any facility to analyze which processes are running and when. More specifically, my process has a response time of anywhere between 3.9s and 3.2s, but this is not random: there are periods of time at 3.9s and periods at 3.2s. Having ruled out blocking I/O, we want to see if some other process is running during the periods at 3.9s.

Comment: You could pass the `-b` option to put `top` in batch mode, then redirect its output.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try and make that work. Sounds like that I need.